# Андроид, разрешение на чтение номера из БД телефона

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-permissions

В приложение делаю запрос что б найти номер телефона, разрешения добавил.

Мой манифест

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ua.zaychenko.eugene.criminalintent">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".CrimeListActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CrimePagerActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".CrimeListActivity" />


</application>
```

Ошибка такая:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data/phones from pid=3572, uid=10083 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
```

Интересно что ошибки нет на эмуляторе с АПИ до 24, от 24 и выше выдает ошибку.
Что не так с разрешением?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начиная с 6 версии Android разрешения нужно запрашивать во время работы приложения.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

https://habrahabr.ru/post/278945/